# Unable to import the net.corda.finance modules in corda

Tags: java, blockchain, corda, corda-flow

I am trying to add cash flow to the example corda app, however I am unable to import the net.corda.finance packages in the clients/controller file (referring 1st screenshot attached). It does not resolve through the import from web option. Not able to get to it by searching either.

I've updated the dependencies in the build.gradle file at the app level (referring 2nd screenshot attached) and the libraries are getting downloaded in the nodes folders and in the external dependencies (referring 3rd screenshot attached).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone please guide if I have missed any steps?

Comment: I managed to solve this by adding the corda.finance module in the classpaths of all the build.gradle files (root, contracts, workflows and client). Adding this note in case if there is anyone else stuck like me!